# Flutterfire can't create new firebase project

Tags: flutter, firebase

> i Found 0 Firebase projects.
> ✔ Enter a project id for your new Firebase project (e.g. my-cool-project) · Firebase-firststep-project
> i New Firebase project Firebase-firststep-project created successfully.
> FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
> COMMAND: firebase projects:create Firebase-firststep-project --json
> ERROR: Failed to create project. See firebase-debug.log for more info.

I'm trying to create a new firebase project using the console, but what I always encounter is the error I listed above.

I got this from firebase-debug.log

> firebaseError: HTTP Error: 400, field [project_id] has issue [project_id contains invalid characters] at responseToError (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\responseToError.js:49:12) at RetryOperation._fn (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\apiv2.js:285:77) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the error message and "See firebase-debug.log for more info"?

Comment: well i got this from firebase-debug.log

firebaseError: HTTP Error: 400, field [project_id] has issue [project_id contains invalid characters]
    at responseToError (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\responseToError.js:49:12)
    at RetryOperation._fn (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\apiv2.js:285:77)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.